# IE7 ms background filter not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter, internet-explorer-7

Short of it is, I'm trying to scale the background image to 100%.

I came across the filter that achieves that goal, however I cant seem to get it to work in ie 7/8. Code is below.

```
  body {
background-image: url(../images/background.gif);
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/background.gif', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/background.gif', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background-size attributes are not very flexible on cross-browser compatibility. It doesn't work because 'background-size' is not supported bellow IE9:

http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Check this post for more detailed information: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

I suggest you find another solution to make this more compatible.

Comment: I'm well aware that background size is css3; my questions pertains to the filters and any possibilities as to why they may not be working, or if more code is needed to make a decision. I also read the page you linked before submitting this replay, and didn't exactly answer what I'm looking for. Thank you though.

Comment: I you check the post I shared above from CSS Tricks you will learn the possibilities of achieving what you want only by CSS.

Comment: When I originally tried the fixes in the article, it broke the page; I did a bit of reworking the code Chris provided and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding a

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

to the `<head>` tag .